# Write a script to change IP tot static

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, network-programming, ip, lan

I have to write a file to change the IP settings to Static with an input for the static IP.
It isn't very hard to write a file that does this(trough BATCH or VBS) but the problem is the name of the connection, standard windows is Local Area Connection, but it has to work with every connection, even if i(for example) rename my connection to test. Also some people have 2 or more connections, and only the standard one should be changed and every other should be disabled(WIFI, Hamachi, etc). It is going to be used on a LAN-Party to quickly change everybody's IP adresses to the given ones(there has to be some kind of input), instead of the manual job(takes to much time with 200+ people).

Can you guys give me some tips/ examples?

Thanks in Advance,
Bart

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago for a similar purpose.

Its a bit laborious but basically it asks the user which Network connection to modify, then asks them if they want to turn on DHCP, or type a manual IP address. I imagine that the logged in user would need administrative rights to change this

```
Option Explicit

Const SCRIPT_NAME = "Set IP"
Const SUBNET_MASK = "255.255.255.0"

Dim objWMI
Dim arrNANames
Dim colNa, objNa
Dim colNAConfig, objNAConfig
Dim strIP
Dim intIPRet
Dim intCount, strSelectString, intSelected

Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colNA = objWMI.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter")

ReDim arrNANames(colNA.Count)
intCount = 0
strSelectString = "Select a network adapter to modify:" & vbCrLf
For Each objNa In colNa
    arrNANames(intCount) = objNA.Name
    strSelectString = strSelectString & intCount & ")  " & arrNANames(intCount) & vbCrLf
    intCount = intCount + 1
Next

Do
    intSelected = inputbox(strSelectString, SCRIPT_NAME)
    If intSelected = "" Or Not IsNumeric(intSelected) Then
        quitScript
    End If
Loop Until CInt(intSelected) < UBound(arrNANames) And CInt(intSelected) > -1

Set colNA = objWMI.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter where Name='" & arrNANames(intSelected) & "'")

For Each objNA In colNA
    Set colNAConfig = objWMI.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID='" & objNA.DeviceID & "'} WHERE resultClass = win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ")
    For Each objNAConfig In colNAConfig
        If MsgBox("Do you want to enable automatic IP (DHCP/APIPA) for device " & chr(34) & objNa.Name & chr(34), vbQuestion+vbYesNo, SCRIPT_NAME) = vbYes Then
            intIPRet = objNAConfig.EnableDHCP
            Select Case intIPRet
                Case 0      MsgBox "DHCP enabled successfully", vbInformation, SCRIPT_NAME
                Case 1      MsgBox "DHCP enabled successfully" & vbCrLf & "Please reboot for changes to take effect", vbInformation, SCRIPT_NAME
                Case Else   MsgBox "Could not enable DHCP", vbCritical, SCRIPT_NAME
            End Select
        Else
            Do
                strIP = inputbox("Type an IP for network adapter: " & objNA.Name, SCRIPT_NAME)
                If strIP = "" Then
                    quitScript
                End If
            Loop Until isValidIP(strIP)
            intIPRet = objNAConfig.EnableStatic(Array(strIP),Array(SUBNET_MASK))
            Select Case intIPRet
                Case 0      MsgBox "IP changed to " & strIP, vbInformation, SCRIPT_NAME
                Case 1      MsgBox "IP changed to " & strIP & vbCrLf & "Please reboot for changes to take effect", vbInformation, SCRIPT_NAME
                Case Else   MsgBox "Could not change IP", vbCritical, SCRIPT_NAME
            End Select
        End If
    Next
Next

quitScript

'returns true if the parameter is a valid IP address
Function isValidIP(ip)
    Dim arrNums, intNum

    arrNums = Split(ip, ".")
    If UBound(arrNums) <> 3 Then
        isValidIP = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    For Each intNum In arrNums
        If Not IsNumeric(intNum) Then
            isValidIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If intNum < 0 Or intNum > 255 Then
            isValidIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        If Len(intNum) > 1 And Left(intNum,1) = "0" Then
            isValidIP = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    isValidIP = True
End Function

Sub quitScript
    Set objWMI = Nothing
    Set colNa = Nothing
    WScript.Quit
End Sub
```